# Clarification of what happens when new thisThing() is called

Tags: c#, .net, object, pointers, garbage-collection

I started my first real codings in C and assembler so I have a question about a constructor effect in c#:

```
class generator()
{
    TcpClient some = new TcpClient(Endpoint);
    while(!some.connected);
    user other = new user(some);
    some = new TcpClient(anotherEndpoint);
}

class user(TcpClient cli)
{
    localTcpclient = cli; //localTcpclient will be stored and used in the future
}
```

Now:
Does calling

> sth = new whatev();

create a new instance of `whatev` **somewhere** in the heap and associate it with sth or is the new object placed where the previous object used to be?

i.e. will `other.localTcpclient` be bound to `Endpoint` or `anotherEndpoint`?
Somehow I think it's the first and that would make sense and be useful, but I'd appreciate some clarification.

Comment: There are many question about "new and heap" so you can search here... in any case check Eric Lippert's article that explains part of the topic (new and value types) and referenced from most of the question on this topic - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does calling
>   `sth = new whatev();`
>   create a new instance of whatev somewhere in the heap and associate it with sth ...?

Yes, that's true. You can imagine this as if writing

```
whatev* sth = new whatev();
```

in C++. Invoking this statement several times wouldn't overwrite the memory occupied by the `whatev` object, but instead create more and more `whatev` instances.
The C# variables are mostely (in case of ref types) *handles* or *references* to objects on the heap. But unlike references in C++, their targets, i.e. the objects referenced, can be changed, and unlike pointers, the referenced objects are enlisted for garbage collection if the handles do not reference them any more.

In your case, `other.localTcpclient` does indeed reference the `TcpClient(Endpoint)` created first. That's because the *reference*, i.e. the object's adress on the heap, is copied to `localTcpclient`. What happens to `some` afterwards is irrelevant for `other`, since it still contains the adress of the original `TcpClient`.

Comment: @Mark - finding what you looking for does not mean it is true :). Post would be better if it states more clearly that strong "yes" applies only to reference types.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov true that, I had to read it twice to actually get the answer to my key question, but I was also looking for some background to extend my knowledge as to how .net is different from what I learnt.